# JSON - If Statement Troubleshooting

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, function, if-statement

What is causing the if statement `(totalViews === 0)` to not function properly?

The statement should be displaying a span tag with in the "`div.viewed`" class. The span's inner text should read "0 people have viewed your post" if the `"totalViews"` equals `0` (no span tags to begin with). However, a span tag is not being inputted at all in to the `"div.viewed"` class.

The remaining if statements seem to be functioning properly.

A sample of the current code:

```
function checkViewers() {
    $('div.viewed').each(function() {
        //Base Variables
        var viewer = $('span.user', this);
        var totalViews = viewer.length;
        var shortenViews = viewer.length -1;
        var viewerCount = $('span', this);

        if (totalViews === 0) {
            $('div.viewed', this).append('<span> 0 people have viewed your post.</span>');
        }
        if (totalViews == 1) {
            $('<span> has viewed your post.</span>').insertAfter(viewer.last());
        }
        if (totalViews == 2) {
            $('<span> and </span>').insertAfter(viewer.first());
            $('<span> have viewed your post.</span>').insertAfter(viewer.last());
        }
        if (totalViews >= 3) {
            $('<span> and </span>').insertAfter(viewer.first());
            $('<span class="user count"></span>').insertAfter(viewerCount.eq(1));
            $('.count', this).html(shortenViews + ' more people');
            $('<span> have viewed your post.</span>').insertAfter(viewer.last());
            viewer.slice(1).hide();
        }

    });
}
```

View the current and complete [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9h6zPEjbA4B8R5FEAr80?p=preview).

Comment: Your loop is `$('div.viewed').each(function() {...});` inside which you expect `$('div.viewed', this).append(...);` to insert something and so it would if the DOM were so constructed but `$(this).append(...);` would seem more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in your traversal. `$('div.viewed', this)` doesn't exist.

Using the context argument of `$(selector,context)` is the same as writing:

```
$(this).find('div.viewed'); //look for descendant of "this"
```

Change:

```
$('div.viewed').each(function() {    
    /* "this" is an instance of div class= viewed*/

     /* look for a div WITHIN "this" with class=viewed"  --BUT  no such descendant*/
    $('div.viewed', this).append(..;    
});
```

TO

```
$('div.viewed').each(function() { 
    /* I'm already here as "this" */   
    $(this).append(..;
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/GJ99qBhzDGhXXNTB1KpY?p=preview)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div.viewed', this).append('<span> 0 people have viewed your post.</span>');
```

here $('div.viewed', this) will return an empty array,

instead you might have to do it like

```
$('div.viewed').append('<span> 0 people have viewed your post.</span>');
```